# Incomplete zip file creation C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've following code which pulls files from S3 and zips them to S3. The problem that I see is when final zip file is created, it's always short of few hundred files. Not sure what's and where is the mistake. Don't get any error for files which are not zipped.

Code:

```
public static async Task StartCompressionLargeDataSetAsync(string dirToZip, int zipBatchSize, List<List<string>> listOf_listOf_pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3Client)
{
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    foreach (var batch in listOf_listOf_pdfFiles)
        await CreateLargeDataSetZipFileAsync(memoryStream, Function.bucket, batch, Function.s3Client);

    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var fileTxfrToS3 = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
    await fileTxfrToS3.UploadAsync(memoryStream, Function.bucket, $"{Function.prefix}{dirToZip}");
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Successfully created {dirToZip}");

    memoryStream.Close();
}

public static async Task CreateLargeDataSetZipFileAsync(MemoryStream stream, string bucket, List<string> pdfFileSet, IAmazonS3 s3Client)
{

    var task = pdfFileSet.Select(async pdfFile =>
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucket,
            Key = pdfFile
        };

        using GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
        using Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream;
        ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(pdfFile.Split('/')[^1]);
        using Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open();
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);

    }).ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(task);
}
```

Comment: There are different versions of the ZIP specification.Not all applications work with all versions of the specification.Also the specification of optional operating modes.  So the most likely reason for not unzipping all the files is the application that zipped files is implimenting modes that are not supported with the app used to unzip.Usually these issues occur when you create a zip file and then later go back and modify an existing zip (deleting or add additional files).The standard zip and unzip methods usually work without issues between different zip/unzip utilities.  The modify doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ZipArchive` is not threadsafe. You can only add one file to the zip archive at a time.

You could try *downloading* multiple files simultaneously and then zipping each one as they complete, but that would have the disadvantage of holding each file entirely in memory while it's being zipped.